# Android MenuItem setShowAsAction() not working

Tags: android, menu

I have a menu item which is set to

```
android:showAsAction="always|withText"
```

in the XML. It inflates correctly and shows properly in the menu bar on my phone. However, if I do the following programatically:

```
item.setVisible(false);
item.setVisible(true);
item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
```

the menu item gets moved to the overflow menu regardless of whether I include the last line of code or not.

Any ideas why this would occur?

Btw I am using a cheap phone to test on which has a hardware menu button.

Many thanks,
Riz

Edit: as requested

Imports

```
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

Styling

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/item_id"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_to_queue"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="@string/menu_title"/>
</menu>
```

Method call:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_id, menu);
   MenuItem mi = menu.findItem(R.id.item_id)
   //Contextual setting of visibility
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you shure you are not mixing [android.view.MenuItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html) with [MenuItemCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html)? can you show your imports and `Activity` styling? or method inside which you are obraining your `item`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I have added an edit above.